# Unable to (re-)install R package from source

Tags: r, devtools, renv

I'm trying to install an R package (`MODifieRDev`) from a GitHub repository, but I'm getting some `gcc` errors which I'm unable to resolve.

I'm using `renv`, and what's strange is that I've installed the exact same package in the same `renv` environment several times before (after removing it with `remove.packages("MODifieRDev")`), but I'm now unable to reinstall it using `devtools::install_git()`.

*(Note that I **can** use `renv::install("MODifieRDev")` to reinstall it from cache, but this doesn't suit me).*

I'm running this on a shared company server, so I cannot discard that something on the server has changed, but currently I don't even know where to look.

Any ideas?

```
> devtools::install_git(url = "https://github.com/ddeweerd/MODifieRDev.git")
Downloading git repo https://github.com/ddeweerd/MODifieRDev.git
'/usr/bin/git' clone --depth 1 --no-hardlinks https://github.com/ddeweerd/MODifieRDev.git /tmp/RtmpqwDAXr/file3ca29d3d72d664
Cloning into '/tmp/RtmpqwDAXr/file3ca29d3d72d664'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 93, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (93/93), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (89/89), done.
remote: Total 93 (delta 8), reused 37 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (93/93), 2.79 MiB | 981.00 KiB/s, done.
── R CMD build ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpqwDAXr/file3ca29d3d72d664/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘MODifieRDev’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘MODifieRDev_0.1.3.tar.gz’
   
Installing package into ‘/home/myuser/HHH/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘MODifieRDev’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -I"/opt/somefolder/software/installed/R-4.2.2-focal/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/myuser/HHH/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c MODifieRDev_init.c -o MODifieRDev_init.o
gcc -I"/opt/somefolder/software/installed/R-4.2.2-focal/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/myuser/HHH/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c complex.c -o complex.o
gcc -shared -L/opt/somefolder/software/installed/R-4.2.2-focal/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o MODifieRDev.so MODifieRDev_init.o complex.o [1] "/tmp/Rtmpr2Y1zB/R.INSTALL3ca87510a75a87/MODifieRDev/src" -L/opt/somefolder/software/installed/R-4.2.2-focal/lib/R/lib -lR
gcc: error: [1]: No such file or directory
gcc: error: "/tmp/Rtmpr2Y1zB/R.INSTALL3ca87510a75a87/MODifieRDev/src": No such file or directory
make: *** [/opt/somefolder/software/installed/R-4.2.2-focal/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: MODifieRDev.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘MODifieRDev’
* removing ‘/home/myuser/HHH/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/MODifieRDev’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpqwDAXr/file3ca29d289d588e/MODifieRDev_0.1.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

This line in the installation log looks suspect:

> gcc -shared -L/opt/somefolder/software/installed/R-4.2.2-focal/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o MODifieRDev.so MODifieRDev_init.o complex.o **[1] "/tmp/Rtmpr2Y1zB/R.INSTALL3ca87510a75a87/MODifieRDev/src"** -L/opt/somefolder/software/installed/R-4.2.2-focal/lib/R/lib -lR

but I wasn't able to reproduce locally, so I'm not sure what could be going on. Did you modify your `~/.R/Makevars` recently?